# How do you find things in general in The Witcher 2, like alt key in the prequel?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I just got through the first game, which was at times a bit vague but generally you always knew where to go, and if you had to find something or someone, you could just run around holding alt. The quest marker was sometimes misplaced, but again, run around with alt and you'd soon enough find the right point.

Now in the second game, I'm having trouble finding anything and I'd be surprised if it's really supposed to be like this. I'm in the first chapter (after the prologue), and at this point none of the quests even have a map marker. I'm supposed to "find info about the she-troll" and "learn more about monster x", but... where? The full map hardly shows anything of use (just merchants and craftsmen, half of which have no label), the z-highlight is pretty useless, half the people outdoors have no label (and it only shows from really close by anyway), and there doesn't seem to be anything else. It's not like there are libraries on the map, or people have an icon over them showing what they do, or that people even have an easily seen name to find them by.

Is this supposed to be done the realistic way, randomly talking to all people around you, randomly entering homes and looking around for the off-chance you'll recognize an item, and randomly clicking on objects to try and interact with them? Seems a bit hard to believe, I gotta be overlooking something.

Comment: Perhaps you could name a concrete mission, with which you are having trouble and we can work with that to solve your issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `z` to use your witcher's medallion to highlight objects around yourself. You need for it to be energised which takes a few seconds. However, the radius and duration are long enough so that it is not really a problem.

As for some quests, you have to find the right person. There is no short cut unless you use a walk-through of which there are many.